# In fastlane upload to testflight, cannot skip build process

Tags: fastlane

Currently, I want upload the developed flutter app to TestFlight.

The upload is successful, but I want to skip waiting during the build process.

I add option skip_waiting_for_build_processing set true and not add changelog.

But, cannot skip waiting during the build process.

Below, my fastlane script and development environment.

Please let me know if there is anything I need to fix. Or, if you know about the same issue, please let me know.

```
lane :beta_dev do
        slack(
            message: "Blah Blah",
            slack_url: "Web hook url",
            default_payloads: [:lane, :git_author, :last_git_commit_hash]
        )
        increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "Runner.xcodeproj")
        build_app(scheme: "dev")
        api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
                  key_id: "KEY_ID",
                  issuer_id: "ISSUER_ID",
                  key_filepath: "KEY_FILE_PATH",
                  duration: 1200, # optional (maximum 1200)
                  in_house: false # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
        )
        pilot(api_key: api_key)
        upload_to_testflight(skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)
        slack(
            message: "Blah Blah",
            slack_url: "Web hook url",
            default_payloads: [:lane, :git_author, :last_git_commit_hash],
            success: true
        )
    end
```

**Environment**

fastlane version : 2.219

OS: MacOS 14.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I think `upload_to_testflight` is an alias for `pilot`, so you should combine those two into one. You're currently calling the same lane twice.

From the [fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/testflight/):

> pilot # alias for "upload_to_testflight"